# set json online image as wallpaper

Tags: android

I am new to android, I am making an android wallpaper app. I store images on google drive and save links in json file in assets folder.The problem is that when i press wallpaper button, wallpaper is not changing but when switch off/on my mobile it changed then. i don't know what happened. i searched more but not find any solution. please help me anyone thanks.

```js
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager ;
Bitmap bitmap1, bitmap2;
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics ;
int width, height;
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable ;

applyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                wallpaperManager  = WallpaperManager.getInstance(activity);

                bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();

                bitmap1 = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();

                GetScreenWidthHeight();

                SetBitmapSize();

                wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(activity);

                try {

                    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap2);

                    wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Toast.makeText(activity,"Image set as Wallpaper",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

public void GetScreenWidthHeight(){

        displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    }

public void SetBitmapSize(){

        bitmap2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap1, width, height, false);
        }
```

Comment: Post the code of `WallpaperManager` please

Answer (score 0):

use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to load image from url and set to wallpaper:

in **.gradle** :

`implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'`

in your **setOnClickListener** :

```
Picasso.with(this) .load(imageUrl).centerCrop() .into(new Target() { 
@Override
public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) { 
  wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap)
}
```

Comment: your idea helped me. Thank you. i used  Glide.with(activity)
                        .load(imageList.get(position).getImgUrl().trim())
                        .into(imageView); and after this wallmanager.setbitmap(bitmap);

Comment: well done :) 
so you can accept my answer as best answer.
good luck